# Excel 2011 for Mac VLOOKUP Date Issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm fairly proficient in using vlookups, but I'm having an issue vlooking up dates between two different spreadsheets.

=VLOOKUP(B6,'[example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1:$AA$260, 19, FALSE)

My formula is retrieving a date fine, but the date is different when the cell is formatted for a date. Yet, when I change the formatting on each spreadsheet to display the date as a number, the number is the same (40115). The dates are displaying differently in each spreadsheet and I can't figure out why, they differ by about 3 years and 1 day (10/30/13 vs. 10/29/09). One was previously .xls, but I saved both a .xlsx.

Thanks.

Comment: I added 1462 to each number after VLOOKUP which resolved the issue, but I'm interested in knowing the root cause of this issue as I know others who have faced it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is from the 1900/1904 date systems that Excel supports. Excel for mac defaults to 1/1/1904 as its date zero, while Excel for windows defaults to 1/1/1900 as its date Zero

The difference is 4 years, or, as you have found out, 1462 days

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162